# Copy RequestParams to RequestHeaders before handling in RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, interceptor

To replace a legacy system and not breaking the interface, I'm looking for a way to implement the following scenario:

If a REST client hasn't set a specific HTTP header (`applicationId`) but sends it as a query-paramter (aka RequestParameter), this value should be taken as a method parameter in a Spring Boot RestController.

The current method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void doSomething(@RequestHeader("applicationId") String applicationId) { }
```

I think there could be two possible ways:

1. Annotate the method *somehow* to map a query-parameter OR a header to a method parameter
2. Write an `Interceptor` which reads all query-parameters of a request and set non-existing headers with their values. This way, the method wouldn't have to be touched at all.

In both ways I'm not sure how to implement them (don't know if *1.* is even possible). I tried with an own `HandlerInterceptor` which reads query-params in `preHandle` (successfully) but isn't able to set headers in the request before it is forwarded to the RestController.

Comment: Write a `Filter` that wraps the request, override the `getHeader` method, first delegate to the actual request, if not available check the parameters. You probably want to limit this to a few well known parameters...

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Are you referring to a `javax.servlet.Filter`? If so, where would you override the `getHeader()` method in there? I think I should add some logic to `doFilter()`

Comment: @user3105453, As an option you can define your own annotation for method parameter (similar to `@RequestParam` or `@RequestHeader`) and write your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` (similar to `RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver` or `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`). Your implementation will look for a value in headers AND in request params. Of course in this case you'll need to mark parameters in all your methods. Dont know will it be OK with you

Comment: Have you read my comment... **Write a `Filter` that _wraps_ the request,** the essential here is wrapping. You can create a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` subclass to wrap the original request and in that subclass override the `getHeader` method. To replace the request you need a filter that isn't doable in an interceptor. The only lines in your filter would something like `filterChain.doFilter(new WrappingRequest(request), response, filterChain);`. The remainder of your code can remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a `Filter` that wraps the incoming request using a `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. This wrapper should override the `getHeader` method.

```
public ParameterToHeaderWrappingRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        filterChain.doFilter(new ParameterToHeaderWrappingRequest(request), response, filterChain);
    }
}
```

Register this filter as a `@Bean` in your Spring Boot application and it will be applied automatically.

```
public class ParameterToHeaderWrappingRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String header = super.getHeader(name);
        if (header == null) {
            header = getParameter(name);
        }
        return header;
    }
}
```

Something like that should do the trick. Depending on your needs you might want/need to override some additional header based methods and you probably want to limit the number of headers to override with parameters.

The rest of your code can now be written as is.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I was able to make it work by changing `getHeader()` to `getHeaders()` and override `getHeaderNames()` too. Looks like `RestController` first looks up all HeaderNames and then iterate through them by calling `getHeaders()`